# Error Code: 3588. Window '<unnamed window>' with RANGE frame has ORDER BY expression of datetime type. Only INTERVAL bound value allowed

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, data-analysis

I need to find the customers who ordered for 3 consecutive days with every order amount greater than $50 for the data in table sales.mytable. This is the SQL query i wrote for this in MySQL workbench.

```
SELECT T.Customer_ID, T.Customer_Name, T.Order_Date
 FROM (SELECT T.*, COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY Order_Date RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) cnt_days
          FROM sales.mytable T
         WHERE Sales>'50')T
 WHERE cnt_days = 3;
```

My sample table looks like this.

```
# Row_ID, Order_ID, Order_Date, Ship_Date, Ship_Mode, Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Segment, Country, City, State, Postal_Code, Region, Product_ID, Category, Sub_Category, Product_Name, Sales
'1', 'CA-2017-152156', '2017-11-08', '2017-11-11', 'Second Class', 'CG-12520', 'Claire Gute', 'Consumer', 'United States', 'Henderson', 'Kentucky', '42420.0', 'South', 'FUR-BO-10001798', 'Furniture', 'Bookcases', 'Bush Somerset Collection Bookcase', '261.9600'
```

And i receive this error. Error Code: 3588. Window '' with RANGE frame has ORDER BY expression of datetime type. Only INTERVAL bound value allowed.

I am sure OVER(ORDER BY Order_Date RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) is a reason but couldnt find any issue. What could be the mistake i made writing this query.

My Table structure is

[image]

Comment: Hi, you need to add the table structure query and maybe query to add sample data.

Comment: *`WHERE Sales>'50'`* The datatype for `sales` column is DECIMAL, so you must use numeric criteria value. Remove quote chars.

Comment: Does the customer may have more than one sale per date? If true then when each sale is less than $50 but total sum is over $50 then does this day must be counted in your query?

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes the customer can hav more than one order per day. But the requirement is to fetch the individual order with order value more than $50.

Comment: If the amount of orders above $50 per day is more than 1 then you'll obtain incorrect data. You'd count not `COUNT(*)` but `COUNT(DISTINCT order_date)`. But MySQL does not implement window version of such function - so you'd obtain distinct dates in previous CTE then count the amount of rows. Alternatively you may calculate the difference between LAG(date) and LEAD(date) over ROWS frame which must be 2 days for matched rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORDER BY expression datatype is DATE. You specify **RANGE** shift - i.e. a shift by the value. So the datatype of the shift must be compatible with DATE.

```
... 
COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY Order_Date 
                RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 DAY PRECEDING 
                          AND INTERVAL 1 DAY FOLLOWING ) cnt_days
...
```

But if your `BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING` means the rows amount then you must use **ROWS** shift, not RANGE.

```
...
COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY Order_Date 
                ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING 
                         AND 1 FOLLOWING ) cnt_days
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works very well and i learned something new from your answer.